# Populate a tableview in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

I have a tableview in javafx which i want to populate with objects type Course. The idea is that in my Course class, I hava a composite primary key which is a diifferent class CourseId. I want to add in one column of the tableview the courseno which is present in CourseId class, but i dont know how to get it.

My course class:

```
package com.licenta.ascourses.ui.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Course implements Serializable {

    private CourseId idCourse = new CourseId();
    private int year;
    private int semester;
    private String discipline;
    private String professor;

    public Course() {

    }

    public Course(CourseId idCourse, int year, int semester) {
        super();
        this.idCourse = idCourse;
        this.year = year;
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    public Course(CourseId idCourse, int year, int semester, String discipline, String professor) {
        this.idCourse=idCourse;
        this.year = year;
        this.semester = semester;
        this.discipline = discipline;
        this.professor = professor;
    }

    public CourseId getIdCourse() {
        return idCourse;
    }

    public void setIdCourse(CourseId idCourse) {
        this.idCourse = idCourse;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getSemester() {
        return semester;
    }

    public void setSemester(int semester) {
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    public String getDiscipline() {
        return discipline;
    }

    public void setDiscipline(String discipline) {
        this.discipline = discipline;
    }

    public String getProfessor() {
        return professor;
    }

    public void setProfessor(String professor) {
        this.professor = professor;
    }



}
```

My courseId class:

```
package com.licenta.ascourses.ui.model;

import java.io.Serializable;



public class CourseId implements Serializable {

    private int idDiscipline;
    private int idProfessor;
    private int courseNo;

    public CourseId()   {

    }

    public CourseId(int idDiscipline, int idProfessor, int courseNo) {
        super();
        this.idDiscipline = idDiscipline;
        this.idProfessor = idProfessor;
        this.courseNo = courseNo;
    }

    public int getIdDiscipline() {
        return idDiscipline;
    }

    public void setIdDiscipline(int idDiscipline) {
        this.idDiscipline = idDiscipline;
    }

    public int getIdProfessor() {
        return idProfessor;
    }

    public void setIdProfessor(int idProfessor) {
        this.idProfessor = idProfessor;
    }

    public int getCourseNo() {
        return courseNo;
    }

    public void setCourseNo(int courseNo) {
        this.courseNo = courseNo;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {

        return 1;
    }

}

columnNumarCurs.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Course, Integer>(""));
        columnAn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Course, Integer>("year"));
        columnSemestru.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Course, Integer>("semester"));
        columnDisciplina.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Course, String>("discipline"));
        columnProfesor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Course, String>("professor"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`setCellValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) method requires a `Callback<CellDataFeatures, ObservableValue>`: i.e. a function that maps a [`CellDataFeatures`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html) object to an `ObservableValue` containing the value to be displayed. Since the value you have is an `int`, and assuming `columnNumarCurs`  is a `TableColumn<Course, Number>`, the appropriate `ObservableValue` type is an `IntegerProperty`. So you can do:

```
columnNumarCurs.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getIdCourse().getCourseNo()));
```